# import a 5GB CSV file into MapD Core?

Tags: csv, import, etl

what's the best way to import a 5GB CSV file into [MapD Core](https://github.com/mapd/mapd-core)?

I've read the docs about [StreamInsert](https://www.mapd.com/docs/latest/mapd-core-guide/loading-data/#streaminsert), but the docs don't seem to offer much guidance about the number of records or the file size that will work well with this approach

```
aws s3 cp s3://mapd.com/streamTest/aws_xmas2015.csv - | \  
/raidStorage/prod/mapd/SampleCode/StreamInsert taxi_xmas_2015 \  
mapd -u mapd -p MapDRocks! --batch 100000
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: eh, mapd-core seems to have APIs to do this, but the docs aren't clear.  since this is a question about `software tools commonly used by programmers`, I'd suggest it's fair game for s/o

Comment: alright, I voted to close too and asked again with more details on the dba stackexchange ‍♀️ https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196536/how-to-import-a-5gb-csv-file-into-mapd-core

Comment: It's a shame that whoever the moderators on dba.stackexchange.com were closed your question there.